# Gap between two drawings in Jetpack compose Canvas

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am trying to make a rectangle and an arc attached to rectangle's bottom. I have used the size provided by the drawScope to lay the drawings on screen but I am unable to get why there is an unnecessary gap between the two drawings even if the specified topLeft parameter of the arc is equal to the height of the rectangle drawn.

```
Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
    ){

        drawRect(
            color = Color(0xFFEF3125),
            topLeft = Offset(0f, 0f),
            size = Size(this.size.width, this.size.height.times(0.75f))
        )

        drawArc(
            color = Color(0xFFEF3125),
            startAngle = 0f,
            sweepAngle = 180f,
            useCenter = false,
            topLeft = Offset(
                0f, this.size.height.times(0.75f)
            )
        )
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a gap because when you draw an Arc you use a rectangle as refefrence but you draw arc to half of the this rectangle so you need to offset up as much as the half of the height of the rectangle that you draw arc into

```
@Composable
private fun ArcSample() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
    ){

        drawRect(
            color = Color(0xFFEF3125),
            size = Size(this.size.width, this.size.height.times(0.75f)),
            style = Stroke(4.dp.toPx())
        )


        drawArc(
            color = Color(0xFFEF3125),
            startAngle = 0f,
            sweepAngle = 180f,
            useCenter = false,
            size = Size(size.width, size.height.times(.25f)),
            topLeft = Offset(
                0f, this.size.height.times(0.625f)
            ),
            style = Stroke(4.dp.toPx())
        )
    }
}
```

I used Stroke style to show bounds, it's for demonstration.

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun ArcSample2() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
    ){

        drawRect(
            color = Color(0xFFEF3125),
            size = Size(this.size.width, this.size.height.times(0.75f))
        )


        val sizeCoefficient = 0.25f

        drawArc(
            color = Color(0xFFEF3125),
            startAngle = 0f,
            sweepAngle = 360f,
            useCenter = false,
            size = Size(size.width, size.height.times(sizeCoefficient)),
            topLeft = Offset(
                0f, this.size.height.times(0.75f-sizeCoefficient/2f)
            )
        )
    }
}
```

[image]